# Date picker shows weird chars instead of arrows

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm using metronic template and the date picker works ok there but when I try to do the same in my page the arrows of my date picker appear as characters, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQBO3.png).

The problem seems to be in the CSS file `plugins.css`, because after rendering pages in metronic the css shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBpjq.png) while my page CSS shows (I'm limited to 2 links so I changed to code):

```
.datepaginator .fa-angle-left::before, .datepicker .fa-angle-left::before {
    content: "ï„„";
}
```

The `plugins.css` files are the same and I think the problem is related to some kind of encoding, but I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Is the CSS file referencing a font file that's missing?

Comment: Going forward, always check your console, which might point out the errors, (F12) in your browser.

Comment: Chrome console does not show any error, neither does firebug on firefox.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the `font-awesome.css` file, try add it like this:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: I was already using that file, so that's not the problem. Also it is the same version that metronic is using.